# Is there a way to resume a Google BigQuery export after it reached the 500 URI quota cap?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm exporting a ~500GB table to google cloud storage as AVRO files, and I hit the 500 URI quota cap. It looks like a hard limit, even though I've given them payment information, and would gladly toss them a few bucks to finish getting my data :-).

Is there any way to resume an export from where it left off? Maybe an undocumented offset parameter in an API? I didn't find one, but figured it was worth asking the community.

[BigQuery Quota Policy](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#quota_policy) for reference.

Comment: Did you turn on gzip compression and use CSV as format? That should shrink the data by quite a bit and you should be under the limit if the original table is just about 500GB. If that fails, you can always split the table into two and export those seperately.

Comment: @MattW. I went with your second suggestion sinve a have a lot of other Avro files, it worked great. I didn't realize how easy it was to split a table. Thanks.